# How to save specific json values in a file?

Tags: php, json

I want to save specific keys and their values in a file, I have this now:

```
<?php

$myfile = fopen("yes.json", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

$json = file_get_contents('https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films');
fwrite($myfile, $json);
fclose($myfile);

?>
```

but it saves the whole json, I want to save just the ids and the titles.

**THANKS**

Comment: No clue as to the data structure of the json

Comment: this is the link : https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films

Comment: You should have a look on the [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way to filter out the **id** and **title** after decoding the JSON response and finally write it on the file after JSON encode.

```
$myfile = fopen("yes.json", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$json = file_get_contents('https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films');
$file_content = [];
$array = json_decode($json,true);
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
  $file_content[] = ['id'=>$v['id'],'title'=>$v['title']];
}

fwrite($myfile, json_encode(file_content));
fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: thanks a lot man. PS its fwrite($myfile, json_encode($file_content));

Comment: Glad it helps you somehow